# Android | Save and restore Fragments which are used in activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a main activity which will contain many fragments let us suppose for now 2 activities A and B Here is the code

> Introduction Activity

```
public class introductionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


private static String TAG = "MyActivity";
private static Fragment fragment ;
public static android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
public static android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_introduction);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "MyFragment");
    }

        fragment = new intro1();
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();


}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, " MyFragment", fragment);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

public static void doStuff(){
    fragment = new intro2();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

Introduction activity(MainActivity) contains FrameLayout which will be replaced by first fragment.

> Fragment 1

```
public class intro1 extends Fragment{

private View rootView;
public static Activity intro1Activity;
public  Button intro1nxtButton;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_intro_1, container, false);

    intro1nxtButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.intro1Next_button);

    intro1nxtButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            introductionActivity.doStuff();
        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}
```

}

First fragment contains a button and and after it is pressed fragment one is replaced by fragment 2

> Fragment 2

```
public class intro2 extends Fragment {

private View rootView;
public static Activity intro2Activity;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_intro_2, container, false);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}
```

}

What i want is when i press back button or close the introduction activity and reopen it it should restore fragment 2 not fragment 1

Comment: Thank you for replying!  This is not working as per my requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have pressed the button and intro2 i.e. 2nd  fragment  is added, then,  pressed the back button and when you come back you get intro1, but  you are hoping for intro2. If I am correct then you code should be like:

if(savedInstanceState != null){fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "MyFragment");} 
If (fragment ==null){fragment=newintro1(); }

And rest will be the same.

Comment: Yes you are correct , I will apply this and let u know thanks

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the answer it should be if(fragment==null){fragment = new intro1;} then it worked perfectly

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it was mitaken. Correct one is
If (fragment == null) {
   fragment = new Intro1();
}